# Is there something wrong with my disk partition?

Tags: partitioning, lvm, fdisk, df

```
# fdisk -l
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    41940991    20719617    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    41940991    20719616   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/a--vm--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Is there a overlap between sda2 and sda5 in terms of start/end?

```
# df
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/a--vm--vg-root 18180876 3424464 13809828 20% /
```

My initial disk is 20G, then I expended a LVM partition but it didn't seem to work?

```
Command (m for help): v
Remaining 41949182 unallocated 512-byte sectors

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5221 cylinders, total 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00094bdb
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of [Master Boot Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) only allows to have four [primary partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Primary_partition). There are cases when one needs more than four partitions and for those [extended partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record) are used. Extended partitions allow having logical volumes within them.

[image]

Your `sda2` is an extended partition and `sda5` is located **within** `sda2`. This is perfectly normal. I don't think the word **"overlapp"** applies here. In your case `sda5` occupies all of `sda2` space, and is the only logical volume, so it might be questionable if such layout is rational. But it is definitely valid.

To expand `sda5`, you would need to expand `sda2` first, provided you have enough unpartitioned  disk space around it.

If you are not very confident with what you are doing I would totally recommend to backup all data first and start using partitioning tool with graphical interface - it will make things easier and more visual. Try using [gparted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) or similar software.

Comment: It is a VMware vm, I clicked the 'expand' button on the UI, and typed in a volume number. I thought everything should be automated. If not, why we even use LVM instead of mounting disks step by step?

Comment: How does that relate to original question and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to expand my disk using LVM. Sorry, I'm newbie.

Comment: Its perfectly OK to be newbie, but you have to be careful with your partitions - otherwise you can lose data. Please read the post carefully. I recommend you to use partitioning tool with graphical interface and try to resize your extended partition first. If in doubt- feel free to post screenshots and questions here.

Comment: Can I create a new extended partition and then a LVM logic partition inside it?

Comment: And I'm operating on a server, can't see UI.

Comment: Yes, but you would lose all data currently stored on existing partition.

Comment: Could you tell me how to enlarge sda2(extended partition) by fdisk, without data loss?

Comment: This is a separate question, that is significantly different from the original one you have asked. You can post a new question.